# How to fix NameError: name 'casts' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I've defined casts in casts function but it still shows NameError. I am new to python, can someone help me? Very thx:)

```py
class Sxxx:
~
~
   def casts(self):
        self.casts = casts
        if self.casts == self.cast_limit:
        print("xxxxxx")
        pass
skkk=Sxxx()
skkk.casts
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "spell.py", line 41, in <module>
summon.casts()
File "spell.py", line 15, in casts
self.casts = casts
NameError: name 'casts' is not defined
```

Comment: Apparently you don't have anything called `casts` defined anywhre in your script.

Comment: When you wrote `self.casts = casts`, where were you expecting the value on the right-hand side to come from?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `casts` is a function, so you must call `skkk.casts()` with brackets.

Comment: That is quite clearly not the issue. OP is getting a `NameError`

Comment: Still not correct. `casts` is not defined when control reaches `self.casts = casts`. Neither as an argument or as a global variable.